# Can I break a property declaration across multiple lines in SASS [syntax]?

Tags: css, sass

I have just recently started using SASS instead of CSS. I am trying to use multiple radial-gradients for the background of my webpage. I don't know how to convert the code into a SASS style:

```
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at top right, rgb(175,140,175), transparent),
            radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom left, rgb(140,140,175), transparent),     
            radial-gradient(ellipse at top left, rgb(175,140,175), transparent),
            radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom right, rgb(140,140,175), transparent)
```

The reason I am having confusion is because the commas at the end of each line seem to be breaking my code, and so I can't have multiple radial-gradients. I know this is an extremely basic question, but unfortunately I haven't been able to find the answer. What would be the proper syntax for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Sass syntax, you can't break up declarations across multiple lines. This should work, with everything on a single line:

```
div
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at top right, rgb(175,140,175), transparent), radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom left, rgb(140,140,175), transparent), radial-gradient(ellipse at top left, rgb(175,140,175), transparent), radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom right, rgb(140,140,175), transparent)
```

You might consider using the SCSS syntax instead, which DOES allow multiple lines, more like regular CSS.

Comment: SCSS would have the same syntax that I originally had except that the last line ends with a semicolon.

I have started to use SCSS rather than SASS, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Why use SASS then at all? I think this is a huge limitation. https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/216

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can:

```
  $layer1: radial-gradient(ellipse at top right, rgb(175,140,175), transparent)
  $layer2: radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom left, rgb(140,140,175), transparent)
  $layer3: radial-gradient(ellipse at top left, rgb(175,140,175), transparent)
  $layer4: radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom right, rgb(140,140,175), transparent)
  background: $layer1, $layer2, $layer3, $layer4
```